# Why my Google OAuth 2 login button is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to learn about OAuth 2 by implementing a login page to my application with google sign-in button. but the button doesn't response or call the signInCallBack() when I click on it, and I don't know what is the problem? .. I already have tried to add onClick action instead of data-callback but this didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--LOAD PRE-REQUISITES FOR GOOGLE SIGN IN -->
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </script>
  <script src="//apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=start"> </script>
  <!-- END PRE-REQUISITES FOR GOOGLE SIGN IN -->
  <style>
.google-button {
  height: 40px;
  border-width: 0;
  background: white;
  color: #737373;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  transition-property: background-color, box-shadow;
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  padding: 0;
}

.google-button__icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 8px 0 8px 8px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.google-button__icon--plus {
  width: 27px;
}

.google-button__text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto',arial,sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button ~ button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
  </style>
</head>


<body>

  <button type="button" id="signinButton" class="google-button">
    <span class="google-button__icon">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 366 372" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M125.9 10.2c40.2-13.9 85.3-13.6 125.3 1.1 22.2 8.2 42.5 21 59.9 37.1-5.8 6.3-12.1 12.2-18.1 18.3l-34.2 34.2c-11.3-10.8-25.1-19-40.1-23.6-17.6-5.3-36.6-6.1-54.6-2.2-21 4.5-40.5 15.5-55.6 30.9-12.2 12.3-21.4 27.5-27 43.9-20.3-15.8-40.6-31.5-61-47.3 21.5-43 60.1-76.9 105.4-92.4z" id="Shape" fill="#EA4335"/><path d="M20.6 102.4c20.3 15.8 40.6 31.5 61 47.3-8 23.3-8 49.2 0 72.4-20.3 15.8-40.6 31.6-60.9 47.3C1.9 232.7-3.8 189.6 4.4 149.2c3.3-16.2 8.7-32 16.2-46.8z" id="Shape" fill="#FBBC05"/><path d="M361.7 151.1c5.8 32.7 4.5 66.8-4.7 98.8-8.5 29.3-24.6 56.5-47.1 77.2l-59.1-45.9c19.5-13.1 33.3-34.3 37.2-57.5H186.6c.1-24.2.1-48.4.1-72.6h175z" id="Shape" fill="#4285F4"/><path d="M81.4 222.2c7.8 22.9 22.8 43.2 42.6 57.1 12.4 8.7 26.6 14.9 41.4 17.9 14.6 3 29.7 2.6 44.4.1 14.6-2.6 28.7-7.9 41-16.2l59.1 45.9c-21.3 19.7-48 33.1-76.2 39.6-31.2 7.1-64.2 7.3-95.2-1-24.6-6.5-47.7-18.2-67.6-34.1-20.9-16.6-38.3-38-50.4-62 20.3-15.7 40.6-31.5 60.9-47.3z" fill="#34A853"/></svg>
    </span>
    <span data-scope="openid email"
    data-clientid="806553823694-6du09kl3dfjk7s294i4gims2p0kh2fpu.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-redirecturi="postmessage" data-accesstype="offline" data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-callback="signInCallback" data-approvalprompt="force">
  </span>
    <span class="google-button__text">Sign in with Google</span>
  </button>

  <div id="result"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function signInCallback(authResult) {
      console.log("Here");
      if (authResult['code']) {

        // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized
        $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');

        // Send the one-time-use code to the server, if the server responds, write a 'login successful' message to the web page and then redirect back to the main restaurants page
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/gconnect?state={{STATE}}',
          processData: false,
          data: authResult['code'],
          contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
          success: function (result) {
            // Handle or verify the server response if necessary.
            if (result) {
              $('#result').html('Login Successful!</br>' + result + '</br>Redirecting...')
              setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = "/restaurant";
              }, 4000);


            } else if (authResult['error']) {

              console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
            } else {
              $('#result').html('Failed to make a server-side call. Check your configuration and console.');
            }

          }

        });
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made changes in code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--LOAD PRE-REQUISITES FOR GOOGLE SIGN IN -->
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </script>

 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
  <!-- END PRE-REQUISITES FOR GOOGLE SIGN IN -->
  <style>
.google-button {
  height: 40px;
  border-width: 0;
  background: white;
  color: #737373;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  transition-property: background-color, box-shadow;
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  padding: 0;
}

.google-button__icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 8px 0 8px 8px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.google-button__icon--plus {
  width: 27px;
}

.google-button__text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto',arial,sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button ~ button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
  </style>
</head>


<body>

  <button type="button" id="signinButton" class="google-button">
    <span class="google-button__icon">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 366 372" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M125.9 10.2c40.2-13.9 85.3-13.6 125.3 1.1 22.2 8.2 42.5 21 59.9 37.1-5.8 6.3-12.1 12.2-18.1 18.3l-34.2 34.2c-11.3-10.8-25.1-19-40.1-23.6-17.6-5.3-36.6-6.1-54.6-2.2-21 4.5-40.5 15.5-55.6 30.9-12.2 12.3-21.4 27.5-27 43.9-20.3-15.8-40.6-31.5-61-47.3 21.5-43 60.1-76.9 105.4-92.4z" id="Shape" fill="#EA4335"/><path d="M20.6 102.4c20.3 15.8 40.6 31.5 61 47.3-8 23.3-8 49.2 0 72.4-20.3 15.8-40.6 31.6-60.9 47.3C1.9 232.7-3.8 189.6 4.4 149.2c3.3-16.2 8.7-32 16.2-46.8z" id="Shape" fill="#FBBC05"/><path d="M361.7 151.1c5.8 32.7 4.5 66.8-4.7 98.8-8.5 29.3-24.6 56.5-47.1 77.2l-59.1-45.9c19.5-13.1 33.3-34.3 37.2-57.5H186.6c.1-24.2.1-48.4.1-72.6h175z" id="Shape" fill="#4285F4"/><path d="M81.4 222.2c7.8 22.9 22.8 43.2 42.6 57.1 12.4 8.7 26.6 14.9 41.4 17.9 14.6 3 29.7 2.6 44.4.1 14.6-2.6 28.7-7.9 41-16.2l59.1 45.9c-21.3 19.7-48 33.1-76.2 39.6-31.2 7.1-64.2 7.3-95.2-1-24.6-6.5-47.7-18.2-67.6-34.1-20.9-16.6-38.3-38-50.4-62 20.3-15.7 40.6-31.5 60.9-47.3z" fill="#34A853"/></svg>
    </span>
    <span data-scope="openid email"
    data-clientid="806553823694-6du09kl3dfjk7s294i4gims2p0kh2fpu.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-redirecturi="postmessage" data-accesstype="offline" data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-callback="signInCallback" data-approvalprompt="force">
  </span>
    <span class="google-button__text">Sign in with Google</span>
  </button>

  <div id="result"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var googleUser = {};
  var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        //scope: 'additional_scope'
      });
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('signinButton'));
    });
  };

  function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {
          //document.getElementById('name').innerText = "Signed in: " +
              googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
              signInCallback();
        }, function(error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
  }

    function signInCallback(authResult) {
      console.log("Here");
      if (authResult['code']) {

        // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized
        $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');

        // Send the one-time-use code to the server, if the server responds, write a 'login successful' message to the web page and then redirect back to the main restaurants page
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/gconnect?state={{STATE}}',
          processData: false,
          data: authResult['code'],
          contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
          success: function (result) {
            // Handle or verify the server response if necessary.
            if (result) {
              $('#result').html('Login Successful!</br>' + result + '</br>Redirecting...')
              setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = "/restaurant";
              }, 4000);


            } else if (authResult['error']) {

              console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
            } else {
              $('#result').html('Failed to make a server-side call. Check your configuration and console.');
            }

          }

        });
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script>startApp();</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is reference document :

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

Note : You need to get client id from project. it will be something like this

```
4234760167137-vud910b6hg4o6svll814nbrrr07mp3qt.apps.googleusercontent.com
```